# Expressing a matrix in terms of four basis matrices

Tags: matrix, algebraic-manipulation

I have five matrices and I want to represent one in the basis of other four. So how do I find the value of coefficients?

For example, if the matrices are `I1`, `I2`, `I3`, `I4`, `T` and the relation between them is

```
T = (a*I1) + (b*I2) + (c*I3) + (d*I4)
```

Now to determine the value of coefficients `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, what do I have to do in *Mathematica*?

I have tried this

```
Solve[{T - a*I1 - b*I2 - c*I3 - d*I4 == 0}, {a, b, c, d}]
```

but it is showing this error:

> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

Comment: Do you have a space between variable names? Anothe thing: dependent on the dimensions of your matrices you may have an overdetermined system.

Comment: Not knowing anything about your matricies, what happens if you try this on your matricies: NMinimize[ Norm[Flatten[T] - (a*Flatten[I1] + b*Flatten[I2] + c*Flatten[I3] + d*Flatten[I4])], {a, b, c, d}, MaxIterations -> 10^4]  When I try that on random Real 3x3 matricies I rapidly get very good approximations of the scalars I used to construct T from I1, I2, I3, I4. If this works for you then you can enhance this with additional precision if needed.

Comment: Please, reopen the question, I have an answer. It is a common task to decompose a matrix as a linear combination of basis matrices (e.g. the Pauli matrices). It can be a duplicate, not an unclear question.

Comment: @ybeltukov I was thinking the same thing. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @ybeltukov Reopened on request.  In the future you are welcome to flag a post ("other") if you have a good answer ready for a closed question.

Answer (score 8):

## LinearSolve

If you have a proper dimensions I recommend you to use `LinearSolve` here. Let us take 4 random matrices as a basis (complex matrices for generality)

```
basis = RandomComplex[1 + I, {4, 2, 2}];
MatrixForm /@ basis
```

[image]

The target matrix

```
T = RandomReal[1, {2, 2}];
T // MatrixForm
```

[image]

We can treat 2x2 matrices as vectors with 4 elements, `Flatten` them and apply `LinearSolve` to find the coefficients

```
v = LinearSolve[Flatten[basis, {{2, 3}}], Flatten[T]]
```

[image]

Validation:

```
Norm[v.basis - T]
```

> 1.26609*10^-16

## Dot

If your matrices are orthogonal to each other (as flattened vectors) you can simply use the matrix multiplication. An example with the Pauli matrices:

```
basis = PauliMatrix@Range[0, 3];
MatrixForm /@ basis
```

[image]

The flattened basis

```
fb = Flatten[basis, {{1}, {2, 3}}]
```

[image]

The basis is orthogonal (but not normalized)

```
fb.ConjugateTranspose[fb] // MatrixForm
nrm = Diagonal[fb.ConjugateTranspose[fb]];
```

[image]

Coefficients

```
v = Flatten[T].ConjugateTranspose[fb]/nrm
```

[image]

Validation

```
Norm[v.basis - T]
```

> 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this for symbolic matrices.

If you want to decompose the matrix `m={{a,b},{c,d}}` into a sum over the Pauli Matrices you just need to define:

```
approx = Total@Table[v[i] PauliMatrix[i], {i, 0, 3}];
vars = Table[v[i], {i, 0, 3}];
m = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
```

The first line gives the sum of the basis matrices with the variable  weights.

The seconde line is a fancy way to get all the variables together. Not really necessary in this small example, but useful for larger ones.

The last definition is the target matrix itself.

Now execute:

```
Solve[m - approx == 0, vars]
```

and you will get the values for all the 'v's.