# Expanding a matrix in a set of matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Consider a vector $a=\{a1,a2,a3\}$. I computed

$e^{i a\cdot \sigma}\qquad \sigma: {\rm Pauli\ matrices}$

and then applied the command *ExpToTrig*.

Now I want to expand the above result in terms of the Pauli matrices and the identity matrix as

$\cos(\sqrt{a1^2+a2^2+a3^2})\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}+\ i\ \frac{\sin{\sqrt{a1^2+a2^2+a3^2}}}{\sqrt{a1^2+a2^2+a3^2}}\Biggl( a1\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}+ a2\begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{pmatrix} + a3 \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}\Biggr)\,,$

How can I do this in mathematica? Also, is it possible in general to expand a given matrix in a set of basis matrices we assign?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you might want to do is write the vector $\vec{a}$ as some magnitude $\theta$ times a *unit vector* `{a1, a2, a3}`.  Then calculate $\exp(i \theta \,a\cdot\sigma)$. This will allow you to get rid of those factors of $\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}$, which are just some $\theta$ anyway.

Here it is in Mathematica:

```
a = \[Theta] {a1, a2, a3};
b = a.Array[PauliMatrix, 3];
c = MatrixExp[I  b];
c//FullForm;
c = c /. Plus[Power[a1, 2], Power[a2, 2], Power[a3, 2]] -> 1;
c // ExpToTrig // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (\theta )+\text{a3} i \sin (\theta ) & \text{a2} \sin (\theta )+\text{a1} i \sin (\theta ) \\
 i \text{a1} \sin (\theta )-\text{a2} \sin (\theta ) & \cos (\theta )-i \text{a3} \sin (\theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

I used `FullForm` to peek at the matrix `c` so I would know how to make the substitution that eliminates the magnitude of the unit vector.

To answer your second question, you can expand any 2x2 matrix $M$ in terms of the set $S$ consisting of the identity matrix and the 3 Pauli matrices, but the coefficients in the expansion will only be real numbers if $M$ is Hermitian.  It is fairly easy to prove this.  You know that the set $T$ of 4 matrices each with a 1 in one position and 0's in the other positions is a basis for any 2x2 matrix.  You can write each matrix in $T$ in terms of the matrices in $S$, but some of the coefficients are complex.  If $S$ is basis for $T$ and $T$ is a basis for all 2x2 matrices ...

Thanks to your comment, we now seek coefficients $c_0, c_1, c_2, c_3$ such that matrix $\hat{c} = c_0 \hat{1} + i\,c_1\hat{\sigma}_1 +i\,c_2\hat{\sigma}_2 +i\,c_3\hat{\sigma}_3$.  Here is one way to do it in Mathematica.  First, create a basis set and a list of coefficients.  Note that we have $i$ times the coefficients of the Pauli matrices, so we explicitly put the $i$ into the list of coefficients. The dot product of the coefficients and the basis is the matrix $m$, which we want to to be equal to the given matrix $c$.  So, we form the equations and solve for the coefficients.  A quick way to display the solution gives a "fair" result, but the Pauli matrices are not in the proper order.  A "better" display can be had using the `Row` function.  Here is the code that takes the previous result for $c$ from above, finds the expansion coefficients and displays the result:

```
basis = Join[{IdentityMatrix[2]}, Array[PauliMatrix, 3]];
coeff = {c0, I c1, I c2, I c3};
m = coeff.basis // Expand;
m // MatrixForm;
eqns = Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[m == c]];
soln = Solve[eqns, {c0, c1, c2, c3}] // First;
fair = coeff.(MatrixForm /@ basis) /. soln
Table[coeff[[k]] MatrixForm[basis[[k]]], {k, 1, 4}];
better = Row[% /. soln, "+"]
```

$$
\cos (\theta )\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) +
i \text{a1} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \sin (\theta )+i \text{a2} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -i \\
 i & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \sin (\theta )+i \text{a3} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \sin (\theta )$$

Factoring out the $i$ and the $\sin\theta$ and putting the Pauli matrix terms in parentheses is a bit trickier.  I don't have a solution for that bit of finesse.

Comment: I could not make myself understood, sorry. Actually, I know how to use MatrixExp and ExptoTig. What I want to know is the command to rewrite the result, which is expressed as one matrix , as a linear combination of matrices (the id. matrix and Pauli matrices in this case.) That is why I wrote down a sum of four matrices above, which is what I want to get eventually.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part, you can use `MatrixExp`. Since you are interested in trigonometric form, I would suggest using polar coordinates from the beginning.

```
p0 = PauliMatrix[0]; p1 = PauliMatrix[1];
p2 = PauliMatrix[2]; p3 = PauliMatrix[3];

a1 = a Sin[q1] Cos[q2];
a2 = a Sin[q1] Sin[q2];
a3 = a Cos[q1];
m = a1 p1 + a2 p2  + a3 p3;

m1 = MatrixExp[I m] // FullSimplify;
m1 // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \cos (a)+i \cos (\text{q1}) \sin (a) & \sin (a) \sin (\text{q1}) (i \cos
>    (\text{q2})+\sin (\text{q2})) \\
>  i e^{i \text{q2}} \sin (a) \sin (\text{q1}) & \cos (a)-i \cos (\text{q1})
>    \sin (a) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

For the second part, I am going to use the method described in [Expressing a matrix in terms of four basis matrices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61274/8070). First we define a basis and then use `LinearSolve`.

```
basis = {p0, p1, p2, p3};
LinearSolve[Flatten[basis,{{2,3}}],Flatten[m1]]// FullSimplify
```

> `Cos[a]`
>
> `I Cos[q2] Sin[a] Sin[q1]`
>
> `I Sin[a] Sin[q1] Sin[q2]`
>
> `I Cos[q1] Sin[a]`

This is basically a compact way of solving equations for all the component at once. You can also proceed in this way. Say `m1 = c0 p0 + c1 p1 + c2 p2 + c3 p3` where `c0,c1,c2,c3` are the unknown coefficients to determine.

```
cp = (c0 p0 + c1 p1 + c2 p2 + c3 p3)
{c0, c1, c2, c3} /.Solve[Flatten@Table[cp[[i, j]] == m1[[i, j]],
                  {i, 2}, {j, 2}], {c0, c1, c2, c3}] // FullSimplify
```

which will give you the same answer.

Comment: Thanks to your edit, I understood that LinearSolve is helpful for my question. Could you explain how the part ''Flatten[basis,{{2, 3}}],Flatten[m1]'' works? I see that Flatten[m1] lines up all the components of m1. However, Flatten[basis,{{2, 3}}] was not clear to me although I read the link you kindly introduced.

Comment: `LinearSolve` is not the only way. It is a compact way solving set of linear equations. You can also use `Solve`. I added it to my answer. `Flatten[basis,{{2,3}}]` is a way to construct a 4x4 matrix from a 2x2x4 array. You can find more example in document center.

Comment: "Flatten[basis,{{2,3}}] is a way to construct a **4x4** matrix from a 2x2x4 array."
I am trying to understand what this means. I see that 2x2x4 means four 2x2 matrices but how do they turn into *4x4*?({{2,3}}??) I would like your further comments.
I found a similar example in the document center:
u = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
Flatten[{{u, 0 u}, {0 u, u}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}] // MatrixForm,
where I do not understand {{1,3},{2,4}}.

Comment: An array is a list with curly brackets say `{{{a1,b1},{c1,d1}},{{a2,...`.When I say 2x2x4, that means it has 4 2x2 matrices. What `Flatten` does is to remove the brackets and bring the elements together. The default order is `Infinity`, so of you use it without an order it will give `{a1,b1,c1,d1,a2,...}`. The arguments in `Flatten` says it where to remove the braces and which element to group. I would suggest to create some arrays with any dimensions an then use `Flatten` with different order. It will give you  some good idea.

Comment: "The arguments in Flatten says it where to remove the braces and which element to group." That sounds clear. I will try some examples to convinvce myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use the function `pauliReduce` that I defined in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86275/245):

```
a = {a1, a2, a3}
(* ==> {a1, a2, a3} *)

a.{σ[1], σ[2], σ[3]}
(* ==> a1 σ[1] + a2 σ[2] + a3 σ[3] *)

pauliReduce[
 MatrixExp[I a.{σ[1], σ[2], σ[3]}]]
```

> $$\frac{1}   {\sqrt{\text{a1}^2+\text{a2}^2+\text{a3}^2}}\left(\hat{1} \sqrt{\text{a1}^2+\text{a2}^2+\text{a3}^2}
>    \cos
>    \left(\sqrt{\text{a1}^2+\text{a2}^2+\text{a3}^2}\right)+
>    i (\text{a1} \sigma (1)+\text{a2} \sigma (2)+\text{a3}
>    \sigma (3)) \sin
>    \left(\sqrt{\text{a1}^2+\text{a2}^2+\text{a3}^2}\right)\right)
> $$

Comment: I appreciate your clear and powerful solution. I will learn a lot from your function, so that I can also consider similar cases where other basis matrices are used, not just the Pauli matrices, hopefully.